# How JAX-RS-jersey-1.12 web server is run as java console application without specified container?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, intellij-idea

IntelliJ created project for web services basing on JAX-RS-jersey-1.12. It can be fun as console app in IDE. How it is possible without Tomcat or other servlet containers? What kind of architecture does this set up uses?

Example code:

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/service")
public class HelloWorld{

public String getClichedMessage() {

    return "Hello";


}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create("http://localhost:8080/");
        server.start();
        }
}
```

Comment: IntelliJ cannot run a webapp without a container. It maybe using jetty server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Jersey (2.6) will work without servlet or http server.

JAR-RS is Servlet-based standard so Jersey requires to be running in a servlet container. It also provides programmatic deployment to the following containers: Grizzly 2 (HTTP and Servlet), JDK Http server, Simple Http server and Jetty Http server.

Comment: I assume it is JDK Http server because of `import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;`. Right?